# Array with implicit size leading to seg fault

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have a old fortran code that I try to update. The arrays were given in subroutines with the old style:

```
double precison A(*)
```

I wanted to changed it to f90 norm:

```
double precison A(:)
```

But I get seg fault by doing so. In the main the array isdeclared as:

```
double precision:: A(size)
```

why can't I change the way of declaring the arr`y in the subroutine?

Thanks

Comment: Please show a full program that displays the problem. Guess: You haven't got an interface in scope at the calling point, but without the code it remains a guess.

Comment: indeed I don't have an interface, I was wondering if it could be that to. I'll try with one

Comment: Assumed shape array dummy arguments ( what you are calling "implicit size" ) require an interface to be in scope at the calling point. This is one reason why you should stick all routines in modules

Comment: agreed. and indeed it was that. thanks